# How to move a range of elements from BytesMut?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a method that takes a mutable instance of BytesMut. I want to move chunks of it into other instances of BytesMut but am not sure about the syntax to do so. Are there any examples out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the range operator on the original buf to move things around or split_off based on some offset value. For example:

```
use bytes::{BufMut, BytesMut};

fn main() {
    let mut buf = BytesMut::with_capacity(64);
    let mut buf_to = BytesMut::with_capacity(64);

    buf.put_u8(b't');
    buf.put_u8(b'e');
    buf.put_u8(b's');
    buf.put_u8(b't');

    // move last 2 elements
    buf_to.put(&buf[2..]);
    println!("{:#?}", buf_to); // b"st"

    // You can also split_off the original value
    let mut another_buf = buf.split_off(2);
    println!("{:#?}", another_buf); // b"st"
    println!("{:#?}", buf); // b"te"
}
```